# Use libcurl in native c to write a Windows service

Tags: c++, windows-services, libcurl

Anyone knows how? I tried but there always is a problem with curl_global_init

"This function is not thread safe. You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init() calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries. "

From this tutorial http://devx.com/cplus/Article/9857#codeitemarea I got my service working correctly, however, just by adding this line:

```
if (rand() == -1) curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

I got error 1053: The service did not response to the start or control request in timely fashion. Even just call curl_version() will cause the bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just issue `curl_global_init()` before you split to threads:

```
int main()
{
  if ( curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL) ) {
    panic();
  }
  // here goes your program
}
```

Comment: A service is not a normal application, and usually has a different structure. In particular, its `main` should call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`, not do initialisation. Initialisation should be done from `SvcMain`.

Answer (score 0):

Install your service as `SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`. Obviously, your own service shouldn't have created any threads either at the point where you call `curl_global_init`. You shouldn't be creating threads before `ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING)` anyway, so this should be no big problem. Just call `curl_global_init` while in state `SERVICE_START_PENDING`.

Comment: From this tutorial http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/9857#codeitemarea I got my service working correctly, however, just by adding this line:
if (rand() == 17) curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
I got error 1053: The service did not response to the start or control request in timely fashion.
Even I follow what u suggested!

Comment: `if (rand()==17` leaves me speechless.

Comment: I mean it happens even when curl_global_init is not run.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with threads, as if you do:

```
if (rand() == -1) curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

then `curl_global_init` is never run.

But curl library has to be linked. And I think this is your problem — your service is unable to find or load this library. Maybe a service cannot find it because without shell it does not have correct PATH.